# In Flutter, how do I pass data into a Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, pass-data, statelesswidget

I'm trying to build my first Flutter app, and have run into difficulty with passing data into Stateless Widgets.  I have the following classes:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new MainBody(),
    );
  }
}


class MainBody extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TimeCheck(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`TimeCheck` is a `Stateful Widget`.  Basically, I want to be able to set some values at the start, and then pass them along to `TimeCheck`, via `MainBody`.  Everything I read shows how to pass data into `Stateful Widgets`, but is it possible to pass it through a `Stateless Widget`?

I recognise I may be taking the wrong approach, so in case it helps, what I'd ultimately like to do is have a "settings" page where the user can set the values for the data (a string and some numbers), and then those values get passed to `TimeCheck` where they're used to generate the display.

I'd also like to be able to save the user-set values if possible, so they don't have to enter them each time, and then I'd like to be able to read them in when `TimeCheck` is instantiated.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes you can do this simply by passing the info to the constructor. Something like this:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp(this.yourData);

  final int yourData;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new MainBody(yourData),
    );
  }
}


class MainBody extends StatelessWidget {
  MainBody(this.yourData);

  final int yourData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TimeCheck(yourData),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass that 'yourData' variable to the padding value in place of 20.0? 
Dart says it is not a constant.

Answer (score 9):

```
class MainMenuCard extends StatelessWidget {
final Choice choice;
final int index;

const MainMenuCard({Key key, this.choice, this.index, Choice Choice, int int})
  : super(key: key);
```

**And Call like this**

```
MainMenuCard(choice : choices[index],int: index)
```

there 'Choice' is Model class (when we using with List.generate) otherwise you can easily pass Data.

```
 final Choice choice;
 const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[]
```